# Is it possible to scale a canvas element

Tags: html, canvas

... and have all of its internal dimensions and interactions remain relative to each other?

For example, with Flash, you can create a movie and publish a .swf file. Then, when you put that .swf file in a page, you can have that movie scale up or down and still maintain all of its functionality with it being none the wiser.

Is something similar with Canvas? I was directed by someone else to the WHATWG description of the scale property, but it was not helpful. Does the scale property do what I want and does anyone have an example?

Thanks!

Comment: What you need is SVG, not Canvas.

Comment: If you mean stretching, then yes, it would be as simple as setting some CSS to stretch shrink based on container size.

Comment: @Shmiddty ... That resized like I hoped, but now all my drag and drop interactions (I'm using KineticJS) and wonky/not really working as expected. So close.

Answer (score 0):

I once solved this by wrapping the Canvas API with functions that used proportional coordinates (ie. 0.3, mapped to 0-1, fixed ratio and other axis relative to this).

Depending on how much work you want to do, you might want to either implement something like this yourself or use some [pre-existing solution](http://jster.net/category/canvas-wrappers).

Comment: I'm actually using KineticJS already. It draws the canvas, sets up draggable elements, etc. When I use the canvas.style.width = whatever to scale it down, the draggable objects no longer work correctly - their handles are still where they would've been had the canvas not been scaled.

Comment: So, switched from KineticJS to oCanvas and now when I use CSS to set the size of the canvas, my interactions still work. Also, I think I'm liking oCanvas better so far. Thanks for the help.